# Nginx does not redirect to the correct port

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect, port

I am using a `docker-compose` to run my `frontend` application, `backend` application and `nginx` webserver. I would like to `redirect the requests to the correct port` (backend or frontend), but for some reason I just get `Internal Server errors`.

This is my `docker-compose`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - project
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - ./nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./project-backend
      dockerfile: stage.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./project-backend/environments/stage.env
    volumes:
      - ./project-backend/src:/usr/src/app/src
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - project

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./project-frontend
      dockerfile: stage.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    networks:
      - project

networks:
  project:
```

This works fine. I can access both of the frontend and backend.

This is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
events {}
http {
    client_max_body_size 20m;
    proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

    server {
        proxy_cache one;
        proxy_cache_key $request_method$request_uri;
        proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
        proxy_cache_methods GET;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1y;
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $1 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reach by service name, instead of localhost.

example:
Change `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/api;` -> `proxy_pass http://backend:3000/api;`

Change `proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;` -> `proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;`